# Can't use substring in my batch rename

Tags: batch-file, substring, rename

I'm trying to batch rename a bunch of files to a portion of their parent folder but I can't seem to extract the part i want from the folder name. Here is what I have:

```
    @echo off
    for /d /r %CD% %%d in (*) do (
        for /f %%b in ("%%~nxd") do (
        set FULLNAME=%%b
        set FILENAME=%FULLNAME:~9,-7%
            for %%f in ("%%~d\??.json") do ren "%%~f" "%FILENAME%_%%~nxf"
        )
    )

pause
```

Again, I'm very inexperienced witch batch and I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: please let us know what actual you want to extract exactly , be specific from  to the file perspective or from a folder name perspective

Comment: The classic __delayed expansion__ trap. Run in a command prompt window `set /?` and read output help. Search on Stack Overflow for __EnableDelayedExpansion__.

Comment: so the folder name always follows the same structure of <ProjectName>.<FolderName>_<Language>. I want to extract only the folder name. I tried with delimiters but the FolderName can contain underscores as wall, so I couldn't isolate it completely. For reference, here was my code:
    `@echo off
    for /d /r %CD% %%d in (*) do (
        for /f "delims=._ tokens=2" %%b in ("%%~nxd") do (
            for %%f in ("%%~d\??.*") do ren "%%~f" "%%b_%%~nxf"
        )
    )
    pause`